# Trouble installing gvr audio sdk for wwise

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr

Google VR just made a VR plugin for wwise :

https://developers.google.com/vr/audio/wwise-getting-started

https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-audio-wwise-sdk

I’m following the google vr user guide installation but it’s not very precise.

I’m not able to « Add GVR Audio Renderer as an effect to the Ambisonic bus. » I only find wwise default plugins.
The user guide says to put copy the files into the wwise installation folder, so I put it there : « Applications/Audiokinetic/Wwise 2016/Wwise »
I think I’m missing something but I don’t know what. Did anyone experienced this issue ?

my wwise version is 2016.2.1 5995 
my unity version is 5.6.0.b9
I running these softs on mac osx 10.11.6

Comment: @Suhaib Janjua can I ask the reason of your vote ? I'm new here, maybe I missed something

Comment: I didn't vote on your post. I'm not the only one who visited your post.

Comment: you're right, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

On a github issue I wrote, Anokta [gave me the solution](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-audio-wwise-sdk/issues/1#issuecomment-282869662)

There is some command lines to write so that wwise can integrate a plugin and also a special location to copy some files :

https://www.audiokinetic.com/library/edge/?source=SDK&id=plugin__install.html